# Check if two adjacent letters in a word are in the same list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am creating a solver for the New York Times' Letter Boxed game. A part of beating the game is to create a word from 4 sets of letters, as long as adjacent letters are not in the same set of words.

I use this piece of code to do this:

```
with open ("words_alpha.txt", "r") as initialWords:
  for line in initialWords:
    exclusive = True
    notAdjacent = True
    
    for a in alphabet:
      if a in line:
        exclusive = False
    
    selected = [char for char in line]
    for s in selected:
      if s in left and selected[selected.index(s) + 1] in left:
        notAdjacent = False
      if s in top and selected[selected.index(s) + 1] in top:
        notAdjacent = False
      if s in right and selected[selected.index(s) + 1] in right:
        notAdjacent = False
      if s in bottom and selected[selected.index(s) + 1] in bottom:
        notAdjacent = False

    if exclusive and notAdjacent and len(line) > 4:
      words.append(line.strip("\n"))
```

The program I have created does work, and I do beat the game if I get lucky, but sometimes the program will have words that have adjacent letters from the same set of words, meaning I need to generate another solution for the game.

For example, here is a solution the program generated that doesn't work:

```
Enter the words on the left: lum
Enter the words on the right: rac
Enter the words on the top: top
Enter the words on the bottom: ind
What is the target number of words? 5
['lait', 'triturator', 'roman', 'nonman', 'nonproduction']
```

As you can see, the word 'triturator' has adjacent letters that appear in the right list, as well as the top list.

Comment: does 2 sets can have a letter in common  ?

Comment: what does your exclusive represent ?

Comment: You could consider using `itertools.pairwise` here. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise For example `for letter, next_letter in selected:` gives you a loop where you get each pair of adjacent letters in turn. Then you can avoid the problematic use of `.index(s) + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The issue is that `x.index("r") + 1` doesn't give give the index of the next letter, in case of duplicate letters in the string

See the following, you want to get the letter after the 2nd `r` and get the `i` because it's after the first `r`

```
>>> x = 'triturator'
>>> x.index("r")
1
>>> x[x.index("r") + 1]
i
```

---

### Solution

You need to search **from** the current letter position

```
selected[selected.index(s, letter_pos) + 1]
```

---

### Improve

- don't need of `exclusive` or `selected` variables
- stop a first `notAdjacent = False`
- use a loop on the 4 sides to reduce code duplicate
- improve variable naming
- use `enumerate` to get the current position, and start the `index` at

```
for line in initialWords:
    notAdjacent = True

    for letter_pos, letter in enumerate(line):
        try:
            next_letter = line[line.index(letter, letter_pos) + 1]
        except IndexError:
            continue

        for side in (left, top, right, bottom):
            if letter in side and next_letter in side:
                notAdjacent = False
                break

        if not notAdjacent:  # no need to continue further investigation
            break

    if notAdjacent and len(line) > 4:
        print(line.strip("\n"))
```